# Django вывод списка

Tags: python, django

Собственно есть кастомная модель:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  colors = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Цвета',
    max_length=100,
    blank=True
)
```

В шаблоне хочу вывести цвета в выпадающем меню примерно так

```
<select class="input-select">
    {% for color in product.colors %}
        <option value="0">{{ color }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Пока писал дошло, что можно сделать так:
{% for color in product.colors.split %}
Этот вариант мне не очень подходит. Есть еще пути решения?

Comment: а что не получается то? в context просто передаете переменную colors, в которой будут лежать все цвета и они спокойно отрендерятся

Comment: Не понимаю как в colors задать список.  При таком выводе {% for color in product.colors %} цикл проходит по нему как по строке

Comment: потому что он должен быть объектом типа QuerySet, а чтобы сделать его таким объектом нужно произвести запрос в БД

Comment: Colors это ведь не отдельный объект в бд, а свойство объека product?
или я совсем не прав?)
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        context['colors'] = ??
        return context

Comment: все верно, вам осталось только сделать запрос в базу данных, чтобы получить QuerySet с цветами,  почитайте про CRUD Django например, [здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-crud-create-retrieve-update-delete-function-based-views/)

Comment: Получил нужный вариант таким способом:
     def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        context['colors'] = self.get_object().colors.split()
        return context 
не уверен что это оптимальный и правильный вариант. Но все равно большое спасибо